# New App 404 - Very Basic Setup - URL Exists

Tags: facebook, http-status-code-404, facebook-canvas

I have created a new Facebook app.  Whenever I visit the canvas page (https://apps.fac...) I get redirected to the Facebook 4oh4 page.

The canvas URL is set to: https://mgnewmedia.com/brandgame/

Which you will see is as basic as it could possibly be, yet I still get a 404.

I have used the debug tool, which does read it fine.  I have checked the URL on other Internet connections and on other Facebook accounts, all 404.  The app's canvas page is: https://apps.facebook.com/brandgame/

I have deleted the app and re-added it with no luck.  I have also tried putting sample apps in place incase it's 404'ing due to no SDK being present, but that's not the case either.

I have a full, valid SSL certificate in place on the hosting, as you can see.  I run several apps on here already with no such issues.

Full list of settings below:
App ID/API Key:
**

App secret:
**

App Namespace:
brandgame

Canvas Page:
https://apps.facebook.com/brandgame/

Canvas URL:
https://mgnewmedia.com/brandgame/

Secure Canvas URL:
https://mgnewmedia.com/brandgame/

Canvas FBML/iframe:
iframe

Contact Email:
**

Support Email Address:
**

App Description:

Comment: I have since got 2 or 3 others to try this on other Internet connections and it appears to be working fine.  I have restarted my Internet connection here and flushed DNS but with no joy.  It's now been 48 hours since the app was created.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug with Facebook, it was listed on their Bug list tracker shortly after I posted this.  It has not yet been resolved, but a work around has been posted.  Essentially you add the app, rename it, then rename it back, waiting 20mins or so between each step.

It's worth noting that this doesn't affect everyone making apps, only certain accounts.  I assume this is down to data centre allocation, or something such like.

Answer (score 0):

If you havent changed anything it will just be the delay in the setup as everything seems to be working fine here?

Can provide screenshot's if you want?